# CssRewriteUrlTransform does not take

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-optimization

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/a/b/c")
    .Include("~/Content/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

I have this bundling. The font-awesome css has a url defined as `url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3')` which is valid when the css is located under `"~/Content/font-awesome.css"` but now its located under "~/a/b"

But `CssRewriteUrlTransform` does not kick in and rewrite path to `url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3')`

**Update:** If I remove the .min file it `CssRewriteUrlTransform`starts to work, bug in web optimization?

https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/166

Comment: Deleting the min css file worked for me, thanks for the 'Update'. I think the bundling tries to skip the minification process if it finds a static min- which bypasses the CssRewriteUrlTransform, does seem like a bug but easy to work around.

Comment: Does seem like an unwise attempt by MS to "optimize" bundling, which leads to hard to debug issue.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem with me.

You need to set the Bundle url relative to the folder of your file.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fontawesomebundle")
    .Include("~/Content/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

**Update:**
It appears that `CssRewriteUrlTransform` doesn't work for `min` file. 
Either use .min file in the include or remove the min file.

Comment: But then you can ass well remove the CssRewriteUrlTransform since it does nothing

Comment: Are you testing in a hosted site (with virtual directory) or in development?

Comment: the bundle by default will use .min file if it exists. that might be the case

Comment: But the transform should be used for min files too

Comment: Turns out min file is used even though it's not included, and that no transform is done when min i used. I had to remove a file that shouldn't be in use to make things work. Nice thinking Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you @Ruchan!  Does seem like an unwise attempt by MS to "optimize" bundling, which leads to hard to debug issue.